# Cant get current Visual Studio instance with System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, process, vsix

I created a new menu for Visual Studio 2013 (VSIX project)

The menu’s functionality related to the Visual Studio instance that clicked on the menu.

I’m getting the current Visual Studio instance with

```
System.Diagnostics.Process vsProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
```

And my use for it is with

```
[DllImport("User32")]
private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int nCmdShow);

ShowWindow((int)vsProcess.MainWindowHandle, 3);
```

But when using the menu it always takes the first Visual Studio instance that was executed, no matter from which instance the menu was clicked.

For example: instance A of visual studio was started, and then B.

No matter from which instance the menu was clicked, it will always choose instance A.

Then I closed A and opened it again (B is still running)

Now when clicking the menu it will choose B.

Any ideas why it is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a solution: Get the DTE object of the current VS instance and take the `MainWindowHandle` from there.

```
EnvDTE.DTE vsDte =  (EnvDTE.DTE)ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SDTE));

var mainWindowHandle = (IntPtr)vsDte.MainWindow.HWnd;

ShowWindow((int)mainWindowHandle, 3);
```